# Adding items to a new column is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to add some items from Arrays to a new column in a listview, this is what i am trying to do:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (listView2.Columns.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < listView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    listView2.SuspendLayout();
                    listView2.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                    listView2.ResumeLayout();
                }
            }

            if (clmnnum[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == 1)
            {
                listView2.SuspendLayout();
                listView2.Columns.Add("Primary Values", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView2.ResumeLayout();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = exp[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = hpe[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = lve[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = stre[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = powe[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = ende[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            }
        }
```

i keep getting an out of range exception about the column, as if it doesn't exist, i can't find out why.

**EDIT**:I forgot to state that the listview has already a first column (0), so that's not it.

Comment: Why are you using listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text  6 times in an assignment?

Comment: it's inside a loop, damn, i didn't include it, sorry one second.

Comment: sure thing. No problem at all. Just trying to understand your code.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios there, it should be quite understandable now, i remove extra columns, add new one, but still says that column indexed (1) does not exist.

Comment: @Omarrio Yeap, it's far more understandable now. What is clmnnum[listBox1.SelectedIndex]?

Comment: clmnnum[] is an array containing how many columns should be added, it has only 3 variables: 1,2,3, it's an array because every single value from another array, has multiple meanings, each meaning gets it's value in a column.

Comment: @Omarrio ok, thanks I got it. One last question, the error you are getting is associated with this listView2.Columns.Add("Primary Values", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left); ? right?

Comment: nope, with **listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[1].Text = exp[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `SubItems`,  insted of  index access... Probably `SubItems` not exists

```
listView2.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].SubItems.Add(powe[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString())
```

I just make a test
this example call `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

```
   listView1.Items.Add("test");
   listView1.Columns.Add("Primary Values", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
   listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = "3232";
```

this works fine

```
   listView1.Items.Add("test");
   listView1.Columns.Add("Primary Values", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
   listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("3232");
```

Comment: EDIT: after more inspection, you were right, to change the text, there must be something to change, to add it, there must be nothing to begin with, thank you.